# React-Redux, error in filtering out item from store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a e-commerce store when user click on add item to cart, it add to redux store.

I have a checkout page where it lists all added item, if user click on remove item, it should be removed from store. Each item in checkout page have `key` as uuid.

I am using uuid to keep unique id for items when added to cart.

Suppose I have 2 items in cart , if user click delete in out item , it dispatches uuid of the item to store,

```
const initialState = {
    items: []
  };
  
  const cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    ...
      case "DELETE": {
        return {
         
          items: [
            state.items.filter((item) => {
              item.uuid !== action.payload;
            }),
          ],
        };  
    ...
  };
  export default cart;
```

But after this all my cart items gets deleted and get warning in console that all items should have unique id.

Each item in state consists of below kind objects,

```
  [{uuid: "uniqueid_1", name:'first'},{uuid: "uniqueid_2", name:'first'}]

  I dispatches an remove action consists of payload as uuid (ie,"uniqueid_1")
```

The complete code reference below,

Action

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const add = (item, quantity) => {
  return {
    type: "ADDTOCART",
    payload: {
      uuid: uuidv4(),
      id: item.id,
      image: item.photo,
      name: item.name,
      price: item.price,
      quantity: quantity,
    },
  };
};

const remove = (item) => {
  return {
    type: "DELETE",
    payload: item,
  };
};

const removeall = () => {
  return {
    type: "REMOVEALL",
  };
};

export default { add, remove, removeall };
```

REDUCER

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

const cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADDTOCART": {
      return { items: [...state.items, action.payload] };
    }
    case "DELETE": {
      return {
        
        items: [
          state.items.filter((item) => {
            item.uuid !== action.payload;
          }),
        ],
      };
    }
    case "REMOVEALL": {
      return { items: [] };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cart;
```

REMOVE ACTION

```
 onClick={() => {dispatch(cartAction.remove(product.uuid));}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed curly braces from filtering and it worked

```
 items: [
          state.items.filter((item) => 
            item.uuid !== action.payload;
          ),
        ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake could be that you now have an array too much. You can change it to:

```
const initialState = {
    items: []
  };
  
  const cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    ...
      case "DELETE": {
        return {
         
          items: 
            state.items.filter((item) => {
              item.uuid !== action.payload.uuid;
            }),
        };  
    ...
  };
  export default cart;
```

This is because state.items.filter will already return an array of objects, so you don't need to wrap it in []

Also Due to the fact that you are using the item as payload for the delete action you need to use `item.uuid !== action.payload.uuid` for comparison

Comment: Thanks, but sorry after changing that got same error, all of my cart items got deleted

Comment: I seen another issue: your payload is the item so you need to compare item.uuid with action.payload.uuid. It may be more economical to only issue uuid as entire action payload for the delete action

Comment: Actually I pass uuid itself as payload

Comment: Can you add the code where you dispatch the delete action?

Comment: Hmm it looks good. The error could still be in `product.uuid`. Have you checked what the actual payload of this is when the action is dispatched (e.g. by adding a console output within the reducer)?

Comment: Hey,I have resolved the issue,please check the answer,Thank you very much for the support

Answer (score 1):

Add the [Spread Syntax(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) here:

```
 items: [
          ...state.items.filter((item) => {
            item.uuid !== action.payload;
          })
],
```

because this:

```
[{uuid: "uniqueid_1", name:'first'},{uuid: "uniqueid_2", name:'first'}].filter(x=>x.uuid!=="uniqueid_1")
```

return an array.
your items array it inside another array at the end, like this:

```
[[{uuid: "uniqueid_1", name:'first'}]]
```

And you need this:

```
[{uuid: "uniqueid_1", name:'first'}]
```